# How many ternary (0, 1, 2) sequences of length 10 are there without any pair of consecutive digits the same? Need help understanding.

Tags: permutations

My work:

$3$ (as there are $3$ choices for first digit) x $2^9$ (only $2$ digits as choices to avoid consecutive digits from then on) x $10$ (permutations where we move the 3 around) = 15360 sequences

But other people are saying that the answer is just $3$ x $2^9$. Can't we move the $3$ around to get $10$ different permutations?

Comment: Other people are right. Think of a case with only (0,1) to choose. There are clearly only 2 sequences and not 20.

Comment: Forgive me for asking, so something like 2 x 3 x 2^8 would be strange because we know (logically) that a sequence can start with 3 numbers (0, 1, 2) so it's illogical to think of it this way where we have two choices to start with correct?

Comment: Oh wait now that I think about it, it makes sense as if we start with 2 then we continue with 2 and would never have a choice of 3 numbers to pick from via the condition stated in the question never mind thank you!

Comment: @TotomaLover2312 but all those cases are covered in $3 \times 2^9$

Comment: Yeah I see that now. Thanks!